# Better ways to compare values in integer arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

What do you Think is the best method to compare values in integer arrays and print the duplicates?

I tried with a `for` loop, however there must be a simpler way to compare them by using methods.
Does the `memcmp`/`wmemcmp` work for this? or perhaps the `Intersect` method?

This is probably a noob question, so I am grateful for any answers that could help me and/or others.

English is not my native language, please excuse my typing errors.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this question and posting one with some sample code on CodeReview. You will probably get an answer. You won't here, because this is where we fix broken code. Note that if you do so, the code must work.

Comment: Better in which sense?  Most concise, best performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to find duplicates in a single array, you can use LINQ:

```
int[] duplicates = theArray
                   .GroupBy(i => i) // Group by the value
                   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1) // Filter to groups with >1 element
                   .Select(g => g.Key) // Take out the value 
                   .ToArray();
```

If you're trying to find matches between two arrays, use `Intersect`:

```
var matches = firstArray.Intersect(secondArray); // Provides elements in both arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] a = new int[] {6, 9, 3, 4};
int[] b = new int[] { 5, 6, 1, 9, 7, 8 };
checkDuplicates = a.Intersect(b).Any();
```

Comment: I tried the Intersect method, however when Printing the `checkDuplicates` out and Intersect found a duplicate. It prints out true. How do i avoid that?